Trouble posting my website online (HTML, JS, GoDaddy, cPanel, and more)
I have been trying to replace a WordPress website with one I have coded myself using HTML, CSS and JS with node.js and react. I have a domain name on GoDaddy with a Web Hosting option. When I connect to it, it send me to my cPanel Admin page.
I've uploaded the entire folder where my website files are in the public_html folder with the File Manager and changed .htaccess to make sure it redirect the request to the index.html file :
RewriteEngine On

DirectoryIndex site/public/index.html site/src/index.js

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.html [L]

Now, when I open the page on Google Chrome, I get a blank page. I can see the code from the index.html file when I inspect the page so i don't know why it won't run the js file and the rest of the code.
see inspect results
I tried to add a console.log on the beginning of my index.js to see if it runs but it never appears on the console.
The folder is build like that :
Website
 |- public
      |- index.html
 |- src
      |- index.js

this is my index.js
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./components/App.jsx";
import { LanguageProvider } from "./LanguageContext.jsx";

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <LanguageProvider>
      <App />
    </LanguageProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

and this is my index.html :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/lemon_milk/lemonMilk.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/meridies_antiqua/meridiesAntiqua.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/typo3/typo3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/raylig/rayligSemiBold.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesSmall.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesMedium.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesLarge.css">

    <title>Production Designer</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="https://colomberaby.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/faviconcolombe.png" sizes="32x32">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="../src/index.js" type="text/jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>


[Edit] your question with a [mcve] (e.g., your index.html and index.js that remains blank).

@StephenNewell I added the two files if it can help, thank you !

Before you move the project from your development environment to production you have to build : npm run build, then deploy : npm run deploy and then upload everything. Is it what you have done?

@MarcAugier I did build but i did not deploy. Since I don't have a deploy script in my package.json, what am I supposed to add ?

My bad, I thought GoDaddy was providing something specific. Hae you checked that post How to deploy react app to godaddy server?

I'll look into it and let you know ! Thank you @MarcAugier

@MarcAugier It seems my Godaddy hosting plan doesn't allow me to run node.js and I need to upgrade it according to the customer service.

Too bad, good luck with that...
